# How can I cast a collection

Tags: c#, collections

This code:

```
IList<string> quids;
quids = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("dbo.getById @Id",
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "Id", Value = 1 });
```

Produces the following error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList'.
>
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Can someone explain to me how I can cast a collection?

Comment: Can you show the code that is causing the error?

Comment: please first of all provide some code and tell us exactly which collection do you want to cast to which collection.

Comment: If you are performing your requests against database don't forget to call for example `ToList()`

Comment: Can you explain where I should call ToList() also.

Comment: @SamanthaJ like this `db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(...).ToList();`

Comment: @SamanthaJ you are trying to convert the representation of a database command to a list. You should be aware that enumerating it or calling `ToList` will execute the database call.

Comment: I would suggest you use a different type than `IList`. In this case, perhaps `IEnumerable<string> quids;` would be better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
IList<string> result = oldCollection.ToList();
```

`DbRawSqlQuery<T>` Does not implement the `IList<T>` interface (so, no direct cast possible). But it implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can call `.ToList()`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `quids` isn't just a collection. Calling `ToList` or even enumerating it will result in a database call. This isn't a matter of casting one collection to another